# Variable resets to zero when entering an ISR C Atmega 328P

Tags: c, atmega

it happens only with "prova", sell, it happens with every variable i try to modify in the Interrupt service routine. The new value remains after exiting the rputine but when entering again it resets to zero and i'm not able to tell wher or why this happens.

I've tried to declare it as volatile int and it doesn't work at all, i've also checked the optimization of my compiler, and one courious fact is that when i use the retard function milisecs seem to update perfectly even when i'm using the same structure.

```
/*
* proyecto far.c
*
* Created: 14/07/2023 17:09:27
* Author : Albuereta
*/

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

/*VARIABLES GLOBALS*/
int boto,milisec, pos_servo =1000; /*pos_servo entre 1000 i 5000*/
int pin,descendent=0;
int prova, tic;
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect)
{
    milisec++;
    TIFR2  = 1<<TOV2;
    TCNT2=130;

}

ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    cli();
    prova=tic;
    prova++;
    tic=prova;
    

    if (prova == 8)// tempo para que el duty cycle dure 1ms
    {
        PORTD&= (0<<PIND6);//
    }
    if (prova >= 154)//tiempo para que el periodo sea de 20 ms
    {
        prova=0;
    PORTD|= (1<<PIND6);// }

    sei();
    return;

}
}

void ini_timer()
{
    TCCR2B = 0x00;        //Disbale Timer2 while we set it up
    TCNT2  = 130;         //Reset Timer Count to 130 out of 255
    TIFR2  = 0x00;        //Timer2 INT Flag Reg: Clear Timer Overflow Flag
    TIMSK2 = 0x01;        //Timer2 INT Reg: Timer2 Overflow Interrupt Enable
    TCCR2A = 0x00;        //Timer2 Control Reg A: Wave Gen Mode normal
    TCCR2B = 0x05;        //Timer2 Control Reg B: Timer Prescaler set to 128

}
void stop_timer()
{
    TCCR2A=0x00;
    TCCR2B=0x00;
}
void retard(unsigned long temps)
{
    milisec=0;
    ini_timer();
    while (milisec<(temps))
    {

    }
    stop_timer();
}
void On_servo(int OCR_variable)
{
    //  int duty;
    //  duty= 15;
    TCCR1A=0x00;
    TCCR1B=0x00;

    DDRB|= (1<< PINB1); //PB 00000010
    TCCR1A = (1 << COM1A1) | (0 << COM1A0) ; // Ponemos a 'bajo' el OCR1A cuando coincida el Compare Match                      10000010
    TCCR1A |=  (1 << WGM11) | (0 << WGM10) ; // Fast PWM: TOP: ICR1
    TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12); // // Fast PWM: TOP: ICR1
    TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | ( 0 << CS10 ); // Preesc = 8// preescaler de 8 que ens permet fer fins a 32 ms
    TCNT1 =0;
    // QUAN EL TCNT1 ES IGUAL A OCR1A o a ICR1 ES PRODUEIX UN FLANC DESCENDENT
    // QUAN EL TIMER TORNA A COMENÇAR ES PRODUEIX UN FLANC ASCENDENT
    ICR1 = 39999;//(16000000/8*freq)-1   formula del datasheet;
    OCR1A =OCR_variable;// valors entre 1000 i 20000 (1000= tope dreta) (5000= tope esquerra)
    retard(250);
    return;


}
void Off_servo(int OCR_variable)
{
    //  int duty;
    //  duty= 15;
    TCCR1A=0x00;
    TCCR1B=0x00;

    DDRB|= (1<< PINB1); //PB 00000010
    TCCR1A = (1 << COM1A1) | (0 << COM1A0) ; // Ponemos a 'bajo' el OCR1b cuando coincida el Compare Match                      10000010
    TCCR1A |=  (1 << WGM11) | (0 << WGM10) ; // Fast PWM: TOP: ICR1
    TCCR1B = (1 << WGM13) | (1 << WGM12); // // Fast PWM: TOP: ICR1
    TCCR1B |= (0 << CS12) | (1 << CS11) | ( 0 << CS10 ); // Preesc = 8// preescaler de 8 que ens permet fer fins a 32 ms
    TCNT1 =0;
    // QUAN EL TCNT1 ES IGUAL A OCR1A o a ICR1 ES PRODUEIX UN FLANC DESCENDENT
    // QUAN EL TIMER TORNA A COMENÇAR ES PRODUEIX UN FLANC ASCENDENT
    ICR1 = 39999;//(16000000/8*freq)-1   formula del datasheet;
    OCR1A =OCR_variable;// valors entre 1000 i 20000 (1000= tope dreta) (5000= tope esquerra)
    retard(250);
    return;

}
/*
void copiar_pwm(int pin_replica)
{
DDRD|=(1<<pin_replica); // fiquem el pin que volguem copiar com a sortida




} // PENDENT*/
void llegir_botons()
{
    //COMPROBACION DE BOTONES
    //establim una prioritat STOP > CALENTAMENT > ASCENSOR > START
    if((PINB & 0x20)==0x20)// BOTO START
    boto=1;
    if((PINB & 0x10)==0x10)// BOTO ASCENSOR
    boto=2;
    if((PINB & 0x04)==0x04)// BOTO CALENTAMENT
    boto=3;
    if((PINB & 0x08)==0x08)//BOTO STOP
    boto=4;
    // FIN COMPROBACION DE BOTONES
    
    
}
void assignar_funcions_botons()
{
    switch (boto)
    {
        case 1: //START
        PORTD|= (1<<PIND5);
        boto=0;
        
        break;
        
        case 2: // ASCENSOR
        PORTD|= (1<<PIND5);
        boto=0;
        break;
        
        case 3: // CALENTAMENT
        PORTD|= (1<<PIND5);
        boto=0;
        break;
        
        case 4: // STOP
        PORTD|= (1<<PIND5);
        boto=0;
        break;
        default:
        boto=0;
        PORTD&= (0<<PIND5);
    }
    
    
}
void mux_sequencial()
{
    
    PORTC=0b00000000;
    
    PORTC=0b00001000;
    
    PORTC=0b00000100;
    
    PORTC=0b00001100;
    
    PORTC=0b00000010;
    
    PORTC=0b00001010;
    
    PORTC=0b00000110;
    
    PORTC=0b00001110;

    return;
    
}
void mux_pin(int pin)
{
    
    switch (pin){
        case 0:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;

        break;
        
        case 1:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00000001;
        break;
        
        case 2:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00000010;
        break;
        
        case 3:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00000011;
        break;
        
        case 4:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00000100;
        break;
        
        case 5:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00000101;
        break;
        
        case 6:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00000110;
        break;
        
        case 7:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00000111;
        break;
        
        case 8:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001000;
        break;
        
        case 9:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001001;
        break;
        
        case 10:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001010;
        break;
        
        case 11:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001011;
        break;
        
        case 12:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001100;
        break;
        
        case 13:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001101;
        break;
        
        case 14:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001110;
        break;
        
        case 15:
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        PORTD|=0b00001111;
        break;
        
        default:
        
        PORTD&= 0b11110000;
        break;
    }
    return;
}
void modificar_pos_servo(int OCR_nou)
{
    OCR1A =OCR_nou;
    retard(250);
    return;
}
void test_servos_mux()
{
    //s'ha diniciar el servo fora de la funcio per a que aquesta el pugue anar movent (ON_servo al main)
    modificar_pos_servo(pos_servo);
    mux_pin(pin);
    pin=pin+1;
    
    if (descendent==0)
    pos_servo=pos_servo+50;
    else pos_servo=pos_servo-50;
    
    if (pos_servo<1500)
    descendent=0;
    if (pos_servo>4500)
    descendent=1;
    if ((pin>2)||(pin<1))
    pin=1;
    retard(20);
    
    
    
}
int main(void)
{
    cli();

    //PINES
    DDRD=0x00;
    //DDRD &= (0<<PIND7)&&(0<<PINB0)&&(0<<PINB4)&&(0<<PINB5);
    DDRD |= (1<<PIND5);
    DDRD |= (1<<PIND6);//pin que saca la señal de los leds los leds
    DDRD |=0b00001111;
    
    DDRB=0x00;
    //DDRB |= (1<<PINB5);
    
    
    DDRC=0X00;
    DDRC|= 0b00001111; //los 4 pirmeros pines son para configurar el mux de leds
    
    //FIN PINES
    
    
    // VARIABLES
    //int boto=0;


    //FIN VARIABLES

    sei();
    TCCR0A = 0x00;        //Disbale Timer1 while we set it up
    TCCR0B = 0x00;        //Disbale Timer0 while we set it up

    //TCNT1  = 130;         //Reset Timer Count to 130 out of 255
    TIFR0  = 0x00;        //Timer1 INT Flag Reg: Clear all interruption flags
    TIMSK0 = 0x03;        //Timer1 INT Reg: Timer1 Overflow Interrupt Enable
    TCCR0A = 0b00000000;        //Timer1 Control Reg A: clear timer on compare match
    TCCR0B = 0b00001010;        //Timer1 Control Reg B: Timer Prescaler set to 128
    
    OCR0A=40;
    
    /* ASIGNACION DE BOTONES
    BOTÓN 1 -> PIN B2 calentament
    BOTÓN 2 -> PIN B3 stop
    BOTÓN 3 -> PIN B4 start
    BOTÓN 4 -> PIN B5 ascensor
    FIN ASIGNACION DE BOTONES */
    while(1)
    {

        //llegir_botons();//ASIGNACION DE PETICION DE BOTON
        //assignar_funcions_botons(); // interpretació de cada petició de botó


    }
}
```

Comment: Look at the disassembly. Declaring variables that are shared between interrupt and main code should help.

Comment: `main()` and `TIMER0_OVF_vect` call no other functions (defined here), as shown; it's not apparent how the other functions might be used, or when, or how you are reading variables to confirm their values (or whether that read is being done atomically). `TCCR0B` seems to have an illegal value (WGM 0b100, mode 4, "reserved").

Comment: If you declare the variable as volatile, does the behavior change?

Comment: volatile lets the compiler know that this variable can be changed externally.  Are your ISR routines at the end of your code?  I'm not certain but moving them to after main() could help too.

Comment: Since `prova` and `tic` are only ever used inside your `ISR(TIMER0_OFV_vect)`, they don't need to be `volatile`. But you have a problem in that you never initialize `tic` with any value at startup.

Comment: I don't see where in your `ISR(TIMER0_OFV_vect)` you clear the Timer0 Overflow flag which caused that interrupt to occur (as you do in `ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect)` with the `TIFR2  = 1<<TOV2;` line). What's probably happening is that this ISR is getting executed over and over (and over and over) as soon as the Timer0 Overflow interrupt happens for the 1st time, and your code is then stuck in that loop for ever.

Comment: It's also usually considered good practice to avoid using global variables unnecessarily, so in that way of thinking you should move your `prova` and `tic` variables inside the `ISR(TIMER0_OVF_vect)` function, and declare `tic` as `static` so that it "remembers" its value: `static int tic = 0;`. It's not necessary for `prova` to be static since it doesn't need to remember its value. But I also question why you need separate variables? What purpose does `prova` serve which couldn't be achieved by just using `tic` alone?

Comment: It's also a little "dangerous" to declare multiple variables on the same line, and initialize the last one, like: `int pin, descendent=0;`. Some people reading that might get the impression that both `pin` and `descendent` are initialized to `0` when in fact `pin` is not initialized by that line.

Comment: I don't see how it can cause the problem but it is unusual to enable the interrupts (sei) within the ISR. That will happen automatically when the ISR exists. Also the 'sei' in main would usually be placed after all initialization.

Comment: Variables magically changing value is something most often caused by stack overflow. This variable won't be allocated on the stack but maybe the stack overflows in such a way that it destroys the data segment. Each time an ISR is called, the MCU automatically stacks certain things, causing stack growth. (Particularly nasty if you have recurring interrupts caused by wrong flag clearing as mentioned above.) Place a breakpoint inside the ISR and check the stack pointer.

Comment: @TimWilliams you were right, i checked the values in TCCR0A and TCCR0B and after changing them into ctc mode and the interrupt name by the compare match one it worked perfectly, thank you so much :))

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> TIFR0  = 0x00;        //Timer1 INT Flag Reg: Clear all interruption flags
> TIMSK0 = 0x03;        //Timer1 INT Reg: Timer1 Overflow Interrupt Enable
> TCCR0A = 0b00000000;        //Timer1 Control Reg A: clear timer on compare match
> TCCR0B = 0b00001010;        //Timer1 Control Reg B: Timer Prescaler set to 128
> ```

Combining bits 3 from `TCCR0B` and 1:0 from `TCCR0A`, `WGM0` seems to be set erroneously to mode 4:

[image: ATmega328P Timer 0 Waveform Generation Modes]

<sup>Source: [Atmel ATmega328P Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-7810-Automotive-Microcontrollers-ATmega328P_Datasheet.pdf) p.86</sup>

While some devices hide undocumented behavior in "reserved" settings, it's my experience that Atmel tends to leave them non-functional when not implemented.  (I haven't tested this particular option on this particular timer, though.)

Choosing a different timer mode will likely get you going.